# Android app crashes/fails when using Titanium Studio 3.3.0.GA

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light').
```

Here's what my tiap.xml looks like:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest>
            <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
        </manifest>
</android>
```

When ever I change it back to what I had previously, which was `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`, the app will crash and I'll get this error:

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Note: I want it to be HoloLight theme.

Comment: checkout [this](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/07/android-appcompat-library/) link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out

This is incorrect (when using 3.3.0):

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

This is correct:

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

You don't need the "android" part after the @ symbol.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you cannot use the normal Theme.Holo.Light style is because your minimum SDK version is 10, which does not support the Holo Light Theme. As such, the compiler is recommending that you change the style used to one that supports the lower SDK for which you are trying to develop. An easy way to fix it this is to just not support older Android versions, but this might not be an option for you.

Since you are working with Titanium Studio, I know that it can be a bit difficult to find a fix when everyone else is using Eclipse and Android Studio (they'll probably tell you that you need to add the support library to your build path or build.gradle, which doesn't exactly translate to Titanium Studio) but I believe this fix should work.

Essentially, what you are going to do is have devices running newer versions of Android use the Holo Light Theme, whereas older versions will just display the older Light Theme. I was going to just write up the instructions on how to do that, but there's an old forum post on Appcelerator's website detailing the exact steps. Here is a link to the specific answer (it's the one with 8 votes):

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130719/how-do-you-build-your-app-with-holo-theme#answer-250415

I believe following those steps should solve the problem.